# Chart with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, charts

Here's my code so far:

```
import os
import re
import sys
import io
import pandas as pd

def load_file(filename):
    df =pd.read_csv('filename', sep='\t', header=None)
    df[0]=pd.to_datetime(df[0], unit='s')
    #print df[0]
    return df

def main():
    df = load_file()
    daily = df.set_index(df[0]).groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='D')) (df[3]).count()
    perday= daily.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='D')).mean()
    my_plot = perday.plot(kind='bar')
    my_plot = perday.sort(columns=df[0],ascending=False).plot(kind='bar',legend=None,title="Total Session per day")
    my_plot.set_xlabel("Date")
    my_plot.set_ylabel("Session")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have  [Http.log](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B8Y76FflvjyxX1ZzZlVlaHN6YUk&usp=sharing) here. I want to make a chart with Pandas to show **how many session in an hour**, but I don't know how to define the

```
[x,y] where x = timestamps and y= sessions
```

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you manage to parse your log-file into pandas DF?

Comment: similar to plt.plot(x, y, linewidth=2.0) check this source for matplotlib   http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html

Comment: @MaxU, yes, I did.  But I have problem to convert the Timestamp to Year-Month-Day

Comment: please post your code for parsing log file and your attempt/error message/etc.

Comment: @MaxU, yes, I did.  But I have problem to convert the Timestamp to Year-Month-Day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to parse/convert UNIX timestamp into Python/numpy/pandas datetime you can do it this way:

```
In [58]: pd.to_datetime('1437775199.837855', unit='s')
Out[58]: Timestamp('2015-07-24 21:59:59.837855')
```

or for the whole DF:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s')
```

represent/print your timestamp in desired format:

```
df['time'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: @EvaMarpaung, please consider opening new question describing "another bugs" in details